# Append 3 bits to start of nsdata

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I am having trouble adding 3 bits to the left side of nsdata (at the start). Here is the java code I am trying to convert to iOS

```
public byte[] getMessageInFormat(final int MessageType, final int MessageNum, final int MessageNum2, byte[] rawMessage){
        byte[][] result = null;
        byte[] byteStream = new byte[rawMessage.length + 3]; 
        byteStream[0] = (byte) MessageType;
        byteStream[1] = (byte) MessageNum;
        byteStream[2] = (byte) MessageNum2;

        for (int i=0; i<rawMessage.length; i++)
        {
            byteStream[3+i] = rawMessage[i];
        }

    return byteStream;

}
```

This doesn't work

```
NSData *rawMessage = [@"hello world" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableData * byteStream = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        [byteStream appendBytes:&MessageType length:sizeof(MessageType)];
        [byteStream appendBytes:&MessageNum length:sizeof(MessageNum)];
        [byteStream appendBytes:&MessageNum2 length:sizeof(MessageNum2)];
        [byteStream appendData:rawMessage];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "having trouble"...as listed, this code shouldn't compile...this line looks suspicious:`[byteStream appendData rawMessage];`  It is missing a `:` after appendData...  Furthermore, what is the data type for `MessageType` and `MessageNum`...are those bytes because they're `int` cast as `byte` in Java?

Comment: sure..thats clearly a type that its missing : after appendData.

Comment: Perhaps you mean bytes, not bits.

Comment: NSData deals in units of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[byteStream appendBytes:&MessageType length:sizeof(MessageType)];
```

Did not work because MessageType is an int and replacing "size of" to 1 works

```
[byteStream appendBytes:&MessageType length:1];
```

Comment: That copies one of the four bytes of MessageType. You don't know how these bytes are stored. Assign unsigned char MessageByte = MessageType; then [byteStream appendBytes:&MessageByte length:1];